# Old domain redirected to new what happens in search index?

Tags: redirects

I have been having issues with another company who have been using a similar domain name to pass as me. After a long battle, I have managed to get them to stop doing that, so what they've done is redirect the old domain to a new one. However the old domain name still shows in the google search.

Will the old domain name stop showing in the index eventually? What about rankings, will the new domain name/website rank for the old one's keywords?

Comment: Yes... the old domain will disappear (1-3 weeks avg). Yes... the new domain will rank equal to that of the old one. Google doesn't punish sites that move from one domain to another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Will the old domain name stop showing in search engines?**

Eventually, search engines will transfer all of the domains authority to the new one. This means the old domain will lose transfer most of its ranking power to the new one.

**Will the new domain name/website rank for the old keywords?**

This really depends on how everything was redirected and other changes.

If the website is the exact same website with a new domain, then the organic ranking power of those keywords will still be there.